# Exception when creating checkboxes dynamically

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Here is my code for creating checkboxes at runtime:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   CheckBox xb = new CheckBox();
                   xb.Text = reader["AnalysisGroup"].ToString();
                   xb.Name = reader["AnalysisGroup"].ToString();
                   xb.SetBounds(100,50, 200, 10);
                   panel1.Controls.Add(xb);                        
                }
            }
```

I get an exception when I run this code:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why does this happen? I am sure than the reader has rows, and I tested that the problem is around adding control code.

Comment: On which object it throws the exception?

Answer (score 2):

`myReader["AnalysisGroup"]` can be null , do as below,

```
if (myReader["AnalysisGroup"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    string val = reader["AnalysisGroup"].ToString();
    CheckBox xb = new CheckBox();
    xb.Text = val;
    xb.Name = val;
    xb.SetBounds(100, 50, 200, 10);
    panel1.Controls.Add(xb);
}
```

Comment: That will still throw a exception I think, if the value truly did `== DbNull.Value` the `.ToString()` would not fail. You need to use [`reader.IsDbNull(theIndexOfAnlysisGroup)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull.aspx) (You can get the index via [GetOrdnal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getordinal.aspx))

Comment: the value of reader isn`t null i tested that by popping its contents by MessageBoxes